# Parallel children using fork()

Tags: c, fork

Can anyone explain me why the following code doesn't stop? I mean, when I run it shows the output but, after that, it doesn't stop(the prompter doesn't appear). I am trying to launch parallel children who are supposed to execute some command (e.g. "ls -l").

```
int main()
{
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!fork()){
            printf("CHILD:\n");
            execlp("ls","ls","-l",".",NULL);
        }
        printf("\n %d \n",i);
    }
    printf("THE END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about some error checking? `fork()` can return -1 to indicate failure. And if any member of the `exec` family returns, it is a failure.

Comment: I tried to check for errors but the problem is still there.

Comment: I don't see any such problem here. You are probably not seeing the prompt because the output of the child processes come after the output of the parent process. If you just press Enter, you'll probably see the prompt.

Comment: It's because you don't `wait()` on your child processes. The parent returns, and shows the prompt, and then your child runs. Your shell wouldn't show the prompt twice under normal circumstances, and it won't here. Add a `wait(NULL);` before `printf("\n %d \n",i);` and you'll see your prompt as you expect. If you examine the output you get right now, chances are high you'll see a prompt just before the first `ls` output, which you wouldn't otherwise see, but not before any additional `ls` outputs.

Comment: I've got it. Thanks @PaulGriffiths for explanation. Just as a matter of fact, ignoring the output and without adding a  wait(NULL) , is this the best way to launch children to work in parallel or there is a better one?

Comment: `fork()` is the *only* way to create child processes. Using threads instead of child processes is another option, which is best depends on what you're trying to do.